# SQL to return distinct values then filter by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select just rows of newly added records, for a specific date, that have not been entered previously?

My source data is:

[image: All data]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Date, IP
FROM
    tblIPs
WHERE
    (Date = '2019-03-25')
```

This returns:

[image]

but 10.0.0.1 does exist previously in the database, so I don't want that to be in my results.

Is there any way I can select unique IP addresses, regardless of the date, and then filter them by the date, 2019-03-25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the IPs that appear on 2019-03-25, and *don't* appear before that:

```
SELECT IP FROM tblIPs WHERE DATE = '2019-03-25'
EXCEPT
SELECT IP FROM tblIPs WHERE DATE < '2019-03-25'
;
```

If you also want to exclude IPs that appear again after 2019-03-25, change the `<` to `<>`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT MIN(Date), IP
FROM tblIPs
GROUP BY IP
HAVING MIN(Date) = '2019-03-25'
```

Comment: This will include IPs that appear *after* 2019-03-25, of course. It's not completely clear if asker wants those included or not.

Comment: @AakashM . . . This returns only IPs whose first date is on `'2019-03-25'`.  There may be subsequent dates, so I have no idea what your comment is referring to.

Comment: to me, from the question text, it's clear that we don't want an IP that appears on 23, 24, 25; it's clear we do want an IP that appears on 25 (only); but it's not completely clear whether we want an IP that appears 25, 26, 27.

Comment: @AakashM . . . The question is:  "How can I select just rows of newly added records, for a specific date, that have not been entered previously?"  It says nothing about subsequent days.

Comment: The 'unique ' in the last sentence sowed uncertainty in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this .

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT A.Date, A.IP
FROM        
   tblIPs A
   INNER JOIN tblIPs B
   ON A.IP <> B.IP
   AND A.DATE <> B.DATE
WHERE     
   (A.Date = '2019-03-25')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Date, IP, row_number() over (partition by IP order by date desc)as recno
FROM         tblIPs ) TT
WHERE     (Date = '2019-03-25') and recno = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your scenario

```
SELECT T.DATE, T.IP
FROM tblIPs as T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT count(id) as count, IP FROM tblIPs
    GROUP BY ip
    HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
) AS A
ON (T.IP = A.IP)
WHERE DATE = '2019-03-25'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking ?

```
SELECT ips.*
FROM tblIPs ips
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblIPs ips1 WHERE ips1.IP = ips.IP AND ips.Date <> ips.Date);
```